# Flutter: always vertical Date Picker

Tags: flutter, dart

A default [Date Picker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html) has a horizontal or vertical flow based on the screen width. On mobile the flow is vertical. On PC and tablets the flow is horizontal like this:

[image: vertical flow]

I tried to limit the width of the showDatePicker by wrapping it inside a sizedbox. The size is decreased, but the flow is still horizontal.

How to force the date picker to always use a vertical flow?

Answer (score 1):

In the Flutter [date range picker](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker), you can use show pickers vertically by setting the [enableMultiView](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/latest/datepicker/SfDateRangePicker/enableMultiView.html) property value as true and [navigationDirection](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/latest/datepicker/SfDateRangePicker/navigationDirection.html) property value as vertical.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/datepicker.dart';
 
void main() => runApp(CellBuilderPicker());
 
class CellBuilderPicker extends StatelessWidget{
 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 100, 50, 100),
            child: SfDateRangePicker(
              view: DateRangePickerView.month,
              selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
              enableMultiView: true,
              navigationDirection: DateRangePickerNavigationDirection.vertical,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```